# My deck dies in a funny pattern -- does that mean this board is upside-down?

Tags: deck, construction

My deck looks like this after it rains.

[image: deck with funny dry pattern]

One board and parts of others are damp for a long time after everything else has dried.  What could cause this and is it hard to fix?

My only guess is that the board is upside down relative to the others.

Comment: Is it possible that just that one board is not sealed, so rain water is soaking into the wood?

Comment: @Niall C.:No boards are sealed yet.  We were told to wait a year to let the wood really dry out.

Comment: yep. not sealed well compared to the others.  not a big deal. seal it went it is dry.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that board may be right under the edge of your roof. Do you have gutters installed? It could be that whenever it rains that board is constantly saturated by roof runoff.

Comment: Could be.  That board is under the sloping part of the roof line, not the flat part (where there are gutters).  I would not expect a lot of rain to run off this part.